# class template vs. member template

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a good rule when to use a class template instead of using member templates?
As I understand it, your are forced to use a class template if your class contains member variable templates but otherwise you are free of choice since this:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    void someMethod(T x);
};
```

behaves like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    void someMethod(T x);
};
```

Is my claim wrong? Or is there any rule of thumb when to use what?

Comment: A template makes sense if using it will reduce code duplication. You can treat it as a technique to help generalize functionality. Use a class template if you need a different type for each set of template parameters. Use a method template if you need a different method for each set of template parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose to make your class a template, rather than having member function templates, for several reasons. Say you have a template parameter `T`.

1. Like you said, if you have a member variable of type `T`, your class needs to be a template.
2. If you have a function returning `T` and not accepting `T`, and you don't want to manually specify the type in each invocation, your class needs to be a template.
3. If you need a virtual function that depends on `T`, your class needs to be a template.
4. If you need a different class layout (i.e. member variables) per instantiation of `T`, your class needs to be a template.
5. If you need to make sure that your functions all operate on a single type rather than generate different versions of them arbitrarily, your class needs to be a template.

The best rule of thumb would be to use the simplest thing that makes sense. In general, member function templates tend to be more rare—and virtually non-existent for the use case you're talking about. Maybe that's no coincidence.

Answer (score 4):

The two are not at all the same. With the first:

```
Foo<int> f;
f.someMethod('a');
```

the called function is `someMethod(int)`.

With the second:

```
Foo f;
f.someMethod('a');
```

the called function is `someMethod(char)`.